# Connection refused with Elasticsearch test container even after adding wait

Tags: elasticsearch, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I'm trying to move the application to write tests using Elasticsearch container. The container does come up and checking its `elasticsearchContainer.isRunning()` status returns true but while making a search request `Connection Refused` exception is thrown. From the [Spring boot, ElasticSearch and TestContainers integration tests. Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028051/spring-boot-elasticsearch-and-testcontainers-integration-tests-connection-refu) I added a wait but the same issue persists.

```
    private static final DockerImageName ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE =
          DockerImageName.parse("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch").withTag("7.11.2");
    elasticsearchContainer = new ElasticsearchContainer(ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE)
                  .withEnv("foo", "bar");
            elasticsearchContainer.addExposedPorts(9200, 9300);
            //elasticsearchContainer.withStartupTimeout(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.MINUTES));
            elasticsearchContainer.setWaitStrategy(
                  Wait.forHttp("/")
                        .forPort(9200)
                        .forStatusCode(200)
                        .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300)));
            elasticsearchContainer.start();
            assert elasticsearchContainer.isRunning() == true;
            System.out.println("ES Get mapped port" + elasticsearchContainer.getMappedPort(9200)); // outputs a random 5 digit number
            try {
                SearchResponse response = getClient(elasticsearchContainer).search(new SearchRequest(), RequestOptions.DEFAULT); // ERRORS OUT HERE
                System.out.println(response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR WHILE getting data " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

The container starts up fine and no error in the logs either:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                              NAMES
48b1cc29fea8   docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.11.2   "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   24 seconds ago   Up 23 seconds   0.0.0.0:64492->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:64493->9300/tcp   vigorous_banzai
d64503cd1a71   testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.3                              "/app"                   25 seconds ago   Up 24 seconds   0.0.0.0:64490->8080/tcp                            testcontainers-ryuk-bc01909a-5fcc-424e-8346-a7560c31c989
```

Any suggestions on how to make the connection work?

Answer (score 1):

Realized that I was using hardcoded ports for creating the rest client. Changed to and it worked

```
    private static RestHighLevelClient getRestHighLevelClient(ElasticsearchContainer container) {
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                                           new UsernamePasswordCredentials(ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME, ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD));
        RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder = RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(container.getHttpHostAddress()))
              .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder
                    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        // Try to prevent SocketTimeoutException when fetching larger batch size
        restClientBuilder.setRequestConfigCallback(
              requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder.setSocketTimeout(2 * 60 * 1000));

        return new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder);
    }
```